# CAS Problem with integrals

Tags: mathematica, integration, maple

I got this problem thrown at me, unfortunately I lack context at the moment but I thought Maple or Mathematica would solve it anyways.

I have a function $f$ over $x$ and $y$ such as this (Maple)

```
f := (y-1.298*exp(-1.311*x)-.3435*exp(.3602*x))*(x-3.059865611)*(y+1.875*exp(-.8384*x)+0.7033e-1*exp(.838*x))*(y+.5774*x+3.533)*(.1291*x^2+0.475e-1*y^2+.6927*x+.7080)*(y-.5773*x-3.533)*c;
```

I have boundary condition so that c needs to be determined to satisfy:

$$
\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}+\frac{d^2f}{dy^2} = -2
$$

```
solution := solve(diff(f, x, x)+diff(f, y, y) = -2, c)
fsubs := subs(c = solution, f)
```

So far so good, now I want to integrate 
$$
\int \left(\frac{df}{dy}-y\right) dx
$$

```
integrate(diff(fsubs, y)-y, x)
```

this is where things no longer work. I may be impatient but I thought ten minutes would be enough.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have tried [Rubi 4.8](http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~arich/) on your problem and it failed with a lot of `$RecursionLimit::reclim2` errors.

Comment: Isn't the `solve` invocation just setting $c=c(x,y) = -2/\nabla^2(f/c)$, not imposing any kind of boundary condition?

Comment: Is $c$ supposed to be a constant or a function of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: I get $c$ as a function of $x$ and $y$